# Can I manage Multiple Clients projects with JIRA

Tags: jira, project

I am liking JIRA a lot, but we need a CLIENT/PROJECT/ISSUE Schema.  Not Just Project and issue.  It seems that Projects in JIRA are actually Clients.  If you have many clients each with its own projects and issues it seems silly that you cant manage clients.  It does so many other things so well, it seems strange.

Comment: How about adding a custom multiselect field named Clients and using a single JIRA project?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. Questions about Jira need to be related to programming not the usage or configuration of Jira.

Answer (score 4):

Some companies indeed use JIRA Project as clients, and use JIRA Components (which are parts of a project) as the projects.

Note that permissions, issue types and other configuration "schemes" in JIRA are configured per-project, not per-component. That means that with this schema you will be able to set up permissions for all issues belonging to a specific client.

Versions are also set per JIRA Project, i.e. per client in this case, which also might not be good.

JIRA also has Project Categories. If you have a small number of clients, you might do better with assigning a client to a project category, and then project will be JIRA project.